# Ionic PWA "Add to homescreen" not working

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I followed the beginner article for building Ionic PWAs:
https://www.joshmorony.com/the-bare-necessities-progressive-web-apps-in-ionic/

1. At what point should I see the "add to homescreen" option?  I hosted the contents of the www folder on a development server with an SSL connection and domain name.  The app works great, but I don't get presented with the homescreen option.
2. When setting the option for "display":"fullscreen" in the manifest.json, shouldn't the browser address bar disappear when accessing the web url of the hosted application?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nothing yet.  It still needs to be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got this working.

1. Make sure your on https and have a valid ssl cert
2. If your app is in a sub-directory, you need to add a scope parameter to your manifest (this is why mine wasn't triggering) and you need to start_url parameter should reflect that as well

Test te app in browser first:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Let me know how that goes!

Comment: Did you happen to get this to work on iOS, as in the iPhone?

Comment: Hi @Joshua , I think I am facing the same problem right i.e its working fine on browsers but when I try to access it from 'Home screen option', my app is not loading on android v6. What do you mean by 
"scope parameter to manifest and start_url parameter should reflect that as well" 
Sorry I am new to Ionic and manifest file couldn't understand :(